# How to Make Post Custom Column Editable

Tags: custom-field, admin-menu

I have a custom post, and a custom column on that post, but there is no way to actually edit the data in that column for any particular post. I tried a few things, including hooking to the `{name}_edit_form` action, but couldn't get anything to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

### Custom Column Code

Below is the code that is called on the `manage_[custom post-type name]_product_columns` filter. This works correctly and creates the column, but there's no UI to edit it when I try to edit a custom post of that type.

```
public static function setCustomProductColumns($columns){
    $columns = [
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __('Name'),
        'pack' => __("Pack")
    ];

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Why isn't my code to save custom fields in quick edit working?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237805/why-isnt-my-code-to-save-custom-fields-in-quick-edit-working).

Answer (score 1):

To edit custom data via the quick edit form you have to add a meta box via the [quick_edit_custom_box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box) action hook. Good examples are provided in the documentation. To edit existing values you need to add some Javascript, which is also available in the provided link.

Comment: This is specifically for quick edit only. I'm talking about the general edit panel, unless the quick edit hook also applies to the normal edit page?

Comment: What is the "general edit panel"?

Comment: When the user clicks on the edit button for a post (not quick edit), they're brought to a new page. I wasn't clear on that, sorry. That's the page I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah! So it's the regular post page. Where does the data from the column come from? Regularly you either save custom post data as post_meta via the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Custom_Post_Type:_.27book.27) hook or by adding a [term/taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Basic_Example) and assign it to them.

Comment: I'm using a custom metadata column. I'm not talking about just the `save_post` hook though; I need to also (I assume) give WordPress some HTML for the input for that data too...which I'm also wondering how to do?

Comment: Where is this custom meta data come from? Where/how is it saved? The meta data needs a relation to a post, or not?

Comment: I'm just using the custom meta data field on a post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to achieve exactly. Do you want to have an editable column like [here](https://www.admincolumns.com/)?

Comment: I just want custom meta data on a post that is editable.

Comment: Please read more about [custom meta data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to grasp how meta data in Wordpress works.

Comment: I did. I don't know how to make the HTML to edit that meta data. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: You don't have to make html to edit the meta data, it's displayed in the custom fields meta box. If you want a custom meta box besides the already existing one you should take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes). Then you need to hook into the `save_post` hook, which I mentioned a couple of comments before.