# Custom Column in CPT admin table not updated after Quick Edit save

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, quick-edit

I have a CPT named `company` with custom fields `url` and `partner`.

Custom column is shown properly with correct content in CPT admin table. Quick fields are also shown and properly populated for each row.

When the Update button is clicked in Quick Edit the post_meta are properly updated, values saved in database, but column's content is not updated by Ajax. If I refresh the page custom column is displayed correctly but the whole point of this Quick Edit is to avoid a page refresh. Client will not know his changes were saved and will keep quick-editing and lose data. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: My problem was because of a caching function related to PODS, a framework I am using for custom port_meta and fields. Row was returned after quick edit but values were cached. I overridden caching for these functions and everything worked properly.

**Full working code with Quick & Bulk Edit**

Custom columns:

```
add_filter(
    'manage_company_posts_columns',
    function () {
        return [
            'cb'           => true,
            'title'        => _x( 'Title', 'column name' ),
            'partner'      => 'Partner',
            'date'         => __( 'Date' ),
            'last_updated' => __( 'Last Updated' ),
        ];
    }
);
```

Custom columns content

```
 add_action(
      'manage_company_posts_custom_column',
        function ( $column, $post_id ) {
            if ( 'last_updated' == $column ) {
                $post_modified = get_post_field( 'post_modified', $post_id );
                if ( ! $post_modified ) {
                    $post_modified = 'Undefined';
                }
                echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $post_modified ) );
            }
            if ( 'partner' == $column ) {
                 if ( get_post_meta( $post_id , 'partner' , true ) !== '0' ) {
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post_id , 'url' , true ) .'">
                          <span class="partner">Partner Company</span></a>';
                 } else {
                    echo 'Not a partner company.';
            }
        }, 10, 2
    );
```

Quick edit fields

```
add_action(
    'quick_edit_custom_box',
    function ( $column_name, $post_type ) {           
        if ( $post_type != 'company' ) return;
        switch( $column_name ) :
            case 'partner': {
                wp_nonce_field( 'company_cpt_quick_edit', 'my_nonce' );
                ?> 
                    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
                        <div class="inline-edit-col">
                            <div class="inline-edit-group wp-clearfix">
                                <label class="alignleft">
                                    <span class="title">Company URL</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="url" value="">
                                </label>
                                <label class="alignleft">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="partner">
                                    <span class="checkbox-title">Partner Company</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php
                break;
            }
        endswitch;
    }, 10, 2
);
```

Save Post action

```
add_action(
    'save_post',
    function ( $post_id ){
        if ( empty( $_POST ) ) return $post_id;
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return $post_id;
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_nonce'], 'company_cpt_quick_edit' ) ) return $post_id;
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
        if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return $post_id;

        if ( isset( $_POST['url'] ) ) {
           update_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', $_POST['url'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['partner'] ) ) {
           update_post_meta( $post_id, 'partner', '1' );
        } else {
           update_post_meta( $post_id, 'partner', '0' );
        }
    }
);
```

JavaScript for quick edit

```
jQuery(function($){

    var wp_inline_edit_function = inlineEditPost.edit;

    inlineEditPost.edit = function( post_id ) {

        wp_inline_edit_function.apply( this, arguments );
        
        var id = 0;
        if ( typeof( post_id ) == 'object' ) {
            id = parseInt( this.getId( post_id ) );
        }
 
        if ( id > 0 ) {
            var specific_post_edit_row = $( '#edit-' + id ),
                specific_post_row = $( '#post-' + id ),
                url = $( '.column-partner', specific_post_row ).find('a:first').attr('href'),
                partner = false;
 
            if( $( '.column-partner', specific_post_row ).find('span.partner').length !== 0 ) partner = true;
 
            $( ':input[name="url"]', specific_post_edit_row ).val( url );
            $( ':input[name="partner"]', specific_post_edit_row ).prop('checked', partner );
        }
    }
});
```

Bulk Edit radio field

```
add_action(
    'bulk_edit_custom_box',
    function ( $column_name, $post_type ) {           
        if ( $post_type != 'company_single' ) return;
        switch( $column_name ) :
            case 'partner': {
                ?> 
                    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
                        <div class="inline-edit-col">
                            <div class="inline-edit-group wp-clearfix">
                                <label class="alignleft">
                                    <input type="radio" id="partner" name="partner" class="partner" value="0">
                                    <label for="partner">Partner</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="non_partner" name="partner" class="partner" value="1">
                                    <label for="non_partner" >Non-partner</label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php
                break;
            }
        endswitch;
    }, 10, 2
);
```

Bulk Edit save function

```
function company_bulk_edit_save_hook() {
    if( empty( $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] ) ) {
        die();
    }
    foreach( $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] as $id ) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['partner'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $id, 'partner', $_POST['partner'] );
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $id, 'partner', '0' );
        }

    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_company_bulk_edit_save', 'company_bulk_edit_save_hook' );
```

AJAX for Bulk Edit

```
jQuery(function($){
    $( 'body' ).on( 'click', 'input[name="bulk_edit"]', function() {

        $( this ).after('<span class="spinner is-active"></span>');
 
        var bulk_edit_row = $( 'tr#bulk-edit' ),
            post_ids = new Array(),
            partner = bulk_edit_row.find( '.partner:checked' ).val();
 
        bulk_edit_row.find( '#bulk-titles' ).children().each( function() {
            post_ids.push( $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /^(ttle)/i, '' ) );
        });
 
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                action: 'company_bulk_edit_save',
                post_ids: post_ids,
                partner: partner
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this not default behaviour? The point of quick edit is to make a change to multiple posts quickly, not to avoid a refresh. E.g. set the author of 10 posts

Comment: You are confusing Quick Edit with Bulk edit.

Comment: The only difference between quick edit and bulk edit is the left most pane

Comment: Infact they use the same code https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js

Comment: Saving the 'Bulk Edit' data is a bit different, see this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238307/160985. However, the point here is not Bulk Edit or how similar it is with Quick Edit. The problem here is after a Quick Edit, columns should update on the spot and they are not even though post_meta data is saved. See the gif in the previous link for the default behavior I am looking for.

Comment: I was responding with a comment to your comment, it was not an answer. The default behaviour you are looking for does not exist. But if not, does the question you linked to not contain your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the Update button is clicked in Quick Edit the post_meta are properly updated, values saved in database, but column's content is not updated by Ajax.

Indeed, the Quick Edit feature makes no attempt to update or reload individual admin columns. It instead replaces the row with whatever the AJAX endpoint returned.

Here is the implementation:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js#L386-L451

```js
    /**
     * Saves the changes made in the quick edit window to the post.
     * Ajax saving is only for Quick Edit and not for bulk edit.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param {number} id The ID for the post that has been changed.
     * @return {boolean} False, so the form does not submit when pressing
     *                   Enter on a focused field.
     */
    save : function(id) {
        var params, fields, page = $('.post_status_page').val() || '';

        if ( typeof(id) === 'object' ) {
            id = this.getId(id);
        }

        $( 'table.widefat .spinner' ).addClass( 'is-active' );

        params = {
            action: 'inline-save',
            post_type: typenow,
            post_ID: id,
            edit_date: 'true',
            post_status: page
        };

        fields = $('#edit-'+id).find(':input').serialize();
        params = fields + '&' + $.param(params);

        // Make Ajax request.
        $.post( ajaxurl, params,
            function(r) {
                var $errorNotice = $( '#edit-' + id + ' .inline-edit-save .notice-error' ),
                    $error = $errorNotice.find( '.error' );

                $( 'table.widefat .spinner' ).removeClass( 'is-active' );

                if (r) {
                    if ( -1 !== r.indexOf( '<tr' ) ) {
                        $(inlineEditPost.what+id).siblings('tr.hidden').addBack().remove();
                        $('#edit-'+id).before(r).remove();
                        $( inlineEditPost.what + id ).hide().fadeIn( 400, function() {
                            // Move focus back to the Quick Edit button. $( this ) is the row being animated.
                            $( this ).find( '.editinline' )
                                .attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' )
                                .focus();
                            wp.a11y.speak( wp.i18n.__( 'Changes saved.' ) );
                        });
                    } else {
                        r = r.replace( /<.[^<>]*?>/g, '' );
                        $errorNotice.removeClass( 'hidden' );
                        $error.html( r );
                        wp.a11y.speak( $error.text() );
                    }
                } else {
                    $errorNotice.removeClass( 'hidden' );
                    $error.text( wp.i18n.__( 'Error while saving the changes.' ) );
                    wp.a11y.speak( wp.i18n.__( 'Error while saving the changes.' ) );
                }
            },
        'html');

        // Prevent submitting the form when pressing Enter on a focused field.
        return false;
    },
```

The function that handles this is `function wp_ajax_inline_save() {`

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e3147c40e91f6eb1f57585724be173e3c04a719/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L1981

Which is the same that powers post updates in the classic editor.

So I tested a custom column with this code:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom columns
 */

add_filter(
    'manage_post_posts_columns',
    function( $columns ) {
        return array_merge( $columns, [ 'tomcol' => 'Toms Awesome Column' ] );
    }
);

add_action(
    'manage_post_posts_custom_column',
    function ( $column_key, $post_id ) {
        if ( $column_key === 'tomcol' ) {
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tomcol', true );
            echo esc_html( $meta );
        }
    },
    10,
    2
);

add_action(
    'quick_edit_custom_box',
    function ( $column_name, $post_type ) {
        if ( 'tomcol' !== $column_name ) {
            return;
        }
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tomcol', true );
        ?>
        <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
            <div class="inline-edit-col">
                <div class="inline-edit-group wp-clearfix">
                    <label class="alignleft">
                        <span class="title">Toms Column</span>
                        <input type="text" name="tomcol" value="<?php echo esc_html( $meta ); ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php
    },
    10,
    2
);

add_action(
    'admin_footer',
    function () {
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            var wp_inline_edit_function = inlineEditPost.edit;
            inlineEditPost.edit = function( post_id ) {
                wp_inline_edit_function.apply( this, arguments );
                var id = 0;
                if ( typeof( post_id ) == 'object' ) {
                    id = parseInt( this.getId( post_id ) );
                }

                if ( id > 0 ) {
                    var specific_post_edit_row = $( '#edit-' + id );
                    var specific_post_row = $( '#post-' + id );
                    var url = $( '.column-tomcol', specific_post_row ).text();
                    $( ':input[name="tomcol"]', specific_post_edit_row ).val( url );
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
);

add_action(
    'save_post',
    function ( $post_id ){
        global $post;
        if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'revision' ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['tomcol'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'tomcol', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['tomcol'] ) ) );
        }
    }
);
```

And it worked. The column updated on AJAX refresh. So I can only conclude that your column is indeed being updated, but with stale values, or a silly mistake/typo has been made somewhere

The important distinction though, is that the column was not updated, but rather the row was replaced completely

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I would like to use default functionality before trying my own. I want a custom column updated just like when quick (or bulk) editing default fields, like Title or Date. Those fields are updated without a page refresh. Isn't this possible for a custom column too?

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer and for confirming that the row should indeed be replaced after quick/bulk edit. The mistake/typo in my code is what I am looking for. Or maybe the fact that my custom column has a php conditional could be the issue. With a simpler column and similar code I had success.

Comment: @GeorgeP I managed to distill your code down to a functioning basic version and have updated my answer, my code works as you expected on my local instance. I did notice the use of a global variable `$post` that was not declared in your save function, but I do not see how that would cause your issue

Comment: @GeorgeP did you discover the difference that caused the problem?

Comment: My problem was because of a caching function related to PODS. Row was returned after quick edit but values were cached. Your comment about "stale values" and the confirmation that code was correct helped me out. I overridden caching for these functions and everything worked properly. I have updated my op with full working code, including the AJAX for bulk edit. Thank you for your help.